# Mindwave device validation in Visual Studio recognizes which COM port it's on, does not connect with device

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bluetooth

I'm using a Neurosky Mindwave headset to interface with the "HelloEEG" demo program that came in the ThinkGear .NET SDK for Visual Studio.

`connector.ConnectScan();` identifies COM3 as the port with the Bluetooth device plugged in, but it won't recognize the device. I wasn't sure if it was a timeout issue (which I read in other questions), so I have it in a loop until it gets any input. Judging by it still scanning after 5 minutes, I would think timing out is not the issue.

Also of note: I have installed everything that came with the headset, but the Bluetooth device still doesn't show up in My Computer.

Could this be a driver problem?

Comment: How's your computer with other bluetooth devices?

Comment: The only other Bluetooth device I use is my phone. I don't have it paired to my computer. It doesn't find it.

Comment: I removed an apparently irrelevant tag, along with "thanks", and polished grammar and formatting to make it a bit more attractive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see Mindwave in your device manager (in COM Ports) as MindWave USB Adapter. If not, it is problem with driver I think. If you are using windows 8 system the MindWave USB Adapter is often overwriting to CH340. Look at this:  [Neurosky](http://support.neurosky.com/kb/mindwave/cant-find-mindwave-or-cant-connect-mindwave-to-application).

You should also remeber to pair USB adapter with headset in MindWave Manager.

Best regards,
Paweł